# Tetris puzzle in the marsh with no use?

Tags: the-witness

I found and solve a puzzle in the Marsh for which i don't find any use

This puzzle is under the water, after the 3 square moving platform.
Here is a picture of the location : [image: puzzle_location]

And here is the puzzle : [image]

Can anyone tell me the purpose of this puzzle ?

Comment: There are several puzzles scattered throughout the game which don't have any purpose, as far as anyone knows.  I'm not sure if this is one of them, though.

Comment: There *is* a purpose: +1 to solved count, of course!

Comment: If you look through the window with the 2 open circles on it, you can see 3 pipe/line looking things. There are 3 solutions to this puzzle. I tried inputting the 3 solutions sequentially, but nothing happened.

Comment: @LapshinDmitry If you're sure that there isn't anything more than this, you might consider write a true answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting in a discussion about purpose of playing the game in the first place... Well, you have +1 solved puzzle for every solved puzzle!

As far as my experience goes, a lot of end-game puzzles are only there to be there, as an additional challenge. This puzzle including: I have not seen any events after solving it.

Even more: AFAIK the game has very direct feedback when something happens: line turns on, there is sound (with a pause after sound for completing the puzzle), etc. Nothing here, so this puzzle is a dead end.